# Why does passing lambda to constrained type template parameter result in `incomplete type` compiler error?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, constraints, c++20

I have a concept that helps me detect the signature of a function:

```cpp
template <typename>
struct FuncHelper;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct FuncHelper<R(Args...)> {
    template <typename Func>
    static constexpr bool is_like = requires(const Func& f, Args... args) {
       { f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) } -> std::convertible_to<R>;
    };
};
template <typename FX, typename T>
concept function_like = FuncHelper<FX>::template is_like<T>;
```

I can use this concept in function overloads as a constraint:

```cpp
template <typename T> requires function_like<bool(), T>
void testWorks(T&& func) { }
// I can call this like testWorks([&](){ return true; });
```

However if I specify this constraint within the template parameters:

```cpp
template <function_like<bool()> T>
void testFails(T&& func) { }
// testFails([&](){ return true; }); // Compiler error: incomplete type
```

then I get a compiler error saying that I have an incomplete type.

Here is the full code:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <typename>
struct FuncHelper;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct FuncHelper<R(Args...)> {
    template <typename Func>
    static constexpr bool is_like = requires(const Func& f, Args... args) {
       { f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) } -> std::convertible_to<R>;
    };
};
template <typename FX, typename T>
concept function_like = FuncHelper<FX>::template is_like<T>;


template <typename T> requires function_like<bool(), T>
void testWorks(T&& func) { }

template <function_like<bool()> T>
void testFails(T&& func) { }

void testAll() {
    testWorks([&](){ return true; }); // No errors!
    testFails([&](){ return true; }); // Compiler error: incomplete type
}
```

You can try it out yourself:

GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/fG6c7E3qf

Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/7G7T8nTde

I thought that both `testWorks` and `testFails` were supposed to do the same thing. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two:

```cpp
template <typename T> requires function_like<bool(), T>
void testWorks(T&& func) { }

template <function_like<bool()> T>
void testFails(T&& func) { }
```

are not equivalent. The latter is equivalent to:

```cpp
template <typename T> requires function_like<T, bool()>
void testFails(T&& func) { }
```

Note the different order of parameters into `function_like`.

---

The issue is that your concept isn't built to handle the type-constraint syntax properly. You need to flip your parameters:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Sig>
concept function_like = FuncHelper<Sig>::template is_like<T>;
```

and then both of these work fine (because now they actually are equivalent):

```cpp
template <typename T> requires function_like<T, bool()>
void testWorks(T&& func) { }

template <function_like<bool()> T>
void testFails(T&& func) { }
```